# FFmpeg list parsers

Tags: ffmpeg

Using FFmpeg `configure`, I can list available parsers:

```
$ ./configure --list-parsers
aac                        dvdsub                     png
aac_latm                   flac                       pnm
ac3                        g729                       rv30
adx                        gsm                        rv40
bmp                        h261                       sbc
cavsvideo                  h263                       sipr
cook                       h264                       tak
dca                        hevc                       vc1
dirac                      mjpeg                      vorbis
dnxhd                      mlp                        vp3
dpx                        mpeg4video                 vp8
dvaudio                    mpegaudio                  vp9
dvbsub                     mpegvideo                  xma
dvd_nav                    opus
```

but how do I list the parsers actually included with my build? `ffmpeg -h`
reveals:

```
-formats            show available formats
-muxers             show available muxers
-demuxers           show available demuxers
-devices            show available devices
-codecs             show available codecs
-decoders           show available decoders
-encoders           show available encoders
-bsfs               show available bit stream filters
-protocols          show available protocols
-filters            show available filters
-pix_fmts           show available pixel formats
-layouts            show standard channel layouts
-sample_fmts        show available audio sample formats
-colors             show available color names
-sources device     list sources of the input device
-sinks device       list sinks of the output device
-hwaccels           show available HW acceleration methods
```

and `ffmpeg -parsers` creates error:

```
Unrecognized option 'parsers'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

Comment: Not implemented, but iterator was recently added, so you can request on trac for feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, you can use this:

```
$ grep --null-data 'ff_.*_parser' ffmpeg | tr '\0' '\n' | head
ff_aac_latm_parser
ff_aac_parser
ff_ac3_parser
ff_adx_parser
ff_bmp_parser
ff_cavsvideo_parser
ff_cook_parser
ff_dca_parser
ff_dirac_parser
ff_dnxhd_parser
```